# Altering animation play state messes up my animation synching with audio

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am synching a div scrolling effect animation with an audio, the synching works fine when I set the element.style.animation property to 'none' when the audio is paused. The problem is when I try to pause the animation instead when the audio is paused. When I pause and play multiple times, the animation is not synched with the audio anymore (animation is too advanced).

```
//This is the audio element
const pupHymn = document.querySelector(".pup-hymn");
//This is the container div of the lyrics
const hymnLyrics = document.querySelector(".lyrics");

const init = () => {
    pupHymn.volume = 0.3;
    //Sync when playing manually 
    pupHymn.addEventListener('play', () => {
        audioTime = pupHymn.currentTime;
        playbackRate = pupHymn.playbackRate;
        hymnLyrics.style.animation = `scroll-effect ${160/playbackRate}s ${(12-audioTime)/playbackRate}s forwards running`;
    );

    pupHymn.addEventListener('pause', () => {
        hymnLyrics.style.animation = 'none'; 
    });

//This works fine.
pupHymn.addEventListener('pause', () => {
        hymnLyrics.style.animation = 'none'; });
}
```

But when I paused the animationPlayState instead, it won't synch properly when I pause and play multiple times.

```
pupHymn.addEventListener('pause', () => {
        hymnLyrics.style.animationPlayState = 'paused'; });
```

I already have tried logging the animation property of my div when the audio will be played, even though the delay is still a positive value, the animation started already.

Comment: Could you create a runnable snippet that demonstrates the problem? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Having said that, I’m not totally surprised that things get out of sync. For example is a graphics processor in use, and is there some buffering?

Comment: @AHaworth I can't seem to upload a mp3 file in a stack snipper so I just made live Github link on it. https://josephh27.github.io/pup_hymn/

Comment: Thanks, I can reproduce the problem now. I think you may need a different method, perhaps using animation delay. I will look at this again later today (UK time!)

Comment: I am already using animation delay (positive and negative) to continue the animation when it is paused and played at a certain audio current time. Unfortunately, when I set the animationPlayState to pause during audio pause the animation starts off even though the animation delay is still positive.

Comment: While I thnk there is a method using animation delay, I don't absolutely know that it will still sync accurately becuase a browser/JS environment is not real-time. Have you instead considered creating an mp4 with the sound included? That would guarantee synchronisation.

Comment: I have not tried it with mp4 but someone already posted the right answer, thanks for all the help and responses guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way here is probably through the [Web Animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API), which allows you to manage the current time of your animation with relatively high precision. You can hook to some events on your `<audio>` element and map its `.currentTime` to the `Animation`'s one (beware the former is in seconds while the latter is in milliseconds).

```js
const audio = document.querySelector("audio");
const target = document.querySelector(".content");
audio.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", (evt) => {
  const { duration } = audio;
  const keys = new KeyframeEffect(
    target,
    [{ transform: "translate(0px, -1300px)" },],
    { duration: duration * 1000, fill: "forwards" }
  );
  const anim = new Animation(keys);
  const sync = () => anim.currentTime = audio.currentTime * 1000;
  audio.addEventListener("seeked", sync);
  audio.addEventListener("play", () => {
    sync();
    anim.play();
  });
  audio.addEventListener("pause", () => {
    anim.pause();
    sync();
  });
}, { once: true });
for (let i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
  const el = document.createElement("p");
  el.textContent = i;
  target.append(el);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  height: 1600px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue);
}
.content p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<audio controls src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/transcoded/d/dc/Strawberry_Fields_Forever_%28Beatles_song_-_sample%29.ogg/Strawberry_Fields_Forever_%28Beatles_song_-_sample%29.ogg.mp3"></audio>

<div class=container>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```